# python getopt not processing flags as expected

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse command line arguments using getopt. It will successfully parse a single argument. When I try to pass multiple arguments, it takes the first flag and leaves everything else in args. Additionally, when I fail to pass arguments with a colon after them in the argument list, the exception doesn't fire.

I have :

```
def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"ns:i:",["num_ratios", "sample=", "iteration="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print ('test.py -s <sampleName -i <iteration>')
        sys.exit(2)
    print (opts)
    print (args)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-n':
            n = arg
        elif opt == '-s':
            sampleName=arg
        elif opt == '-i':
            iteration = arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

If I then execute:

```
python calculateRatios.py -n 1 -s wibble
```

I get

```
[('-n', '')]
['1', '-s', 'wibble']
```

which says to me that it's picking up -n as an option but not associating the value 1 with it, then it's stopping. It's not finding further flags as so not assigning values.

When I then execute:

```
python calculateRatios.py -n 1
```

my understanding is that the exception should kick off as I've got a colon after the s in the getopt.getopt call. It doesn't, instead I get

```
[('-n', '')]
['1']
```

In both of these examples, there's an empty string in opt, that I don't know where it's coming from. Is that the problem? Where's it from? I'm guessing it's something small that I've missed.
I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected. You have to put a colon or parameter won't be associated to `n` option, and `n` option is just a switch. Arg parsing is desynchronized after that, and since `getopt` doesn't encounter another option it assumes some other non-option arguments are passed.

Fix it like that.

```
"n:s:i:",["num_ratios=", "sample=", "iteration="]
```

Note that the only way you're getting an exception is by passing argument-required argument without argument at the end of the command line, otherwise, other switches/arguments are consumed.

What I did to prevent users from omitting the arguments and desynchronize argument parsing - which is applicable most of the time - is to test that `arg` doesn't start with `-` (most arguments don't start by `-`) like this:

```
for opt, arg in opts:
    if arg.startswith("-"):
        raise Exception("Argument omitted for {}".format(opt))
    if opt == '-n':
        n = arg
    elif opt == '-s':
        sampleName=arg
    elif opt == '-i':
        iteration = arg
```

that doesn't work so well if option argument can start with `-`, but in most case it cannot.